# ValueNotifier not chaning icon button color - I have to call setState()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple app, that does the below.

1. Check if file is in storage.
2. If not in storage, then download the file. If it's in storage then notify the user.
3. Again, if the file is in storage, then the change the download icon button to blue. If the file is not in storage or is deleted, then change the download icon button to red.

The above is working but when I download or delete a file I have to call `setState()` to refresh the widgets, and this updates the whole widget tree while I only want to update that one widget (download icon button).

I have implemented `ValueListenableBuilder` but the icon does not change immediately. I have to call `setState()`.

```dart
              ListTile(
                horizontalTitleGap: 2,
                title: const Text('Paper 1 (English)'),
                trailing: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                  future: checkFile(file_name.accP1Nov2020),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
                    }
    
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                    }
                  
                        
                    late bool fileExists = snapshot.data ?? false;
                    
                    ValueNotifier<bool> fileNotifier = ValueNotifier(fileExists);
                    
    
                    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                        valueListenable: fileNotifier,
                        builder: (context, value, child) {
                        
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  downloadPaper.downloadPaper(
                                    context,
                                    link.accP1Nov2020,
                                    file_name.accP1Nov2020,
                                  );
                                      
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.download_sharp),
                                color: value ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
                                tooltip: 'Offline Download',
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (ctx) => Center(
                                      child: AlertDialog(
                                        title: const Text('Delete'),
                                        content: const Text('Delete from storage?'),
                                        actions: [
                                          Center(
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                              children: [
                                                ElevatedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                                                  },
                                                  child: const Text('No'),
                                                ),
                                                ElevatedButton(
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    downloadPaper.deleteFile(
                                                      context,
                                                      file_name.accP1Nov2020,
                                                    );
                                                    
                                                  },
                                                  child: const Text('Yes'),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever_outlined),
                                tooltip: 'Delete',
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        });
                  },
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PdfViewer(
                        subjectLink: link.accP1Nov2020,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

The class simplified (I removed some lines of code to make it simple):

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:past_papers/download_paper.dart';
import 'package:past_papers/screens/pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:past_papers/constants/links.dart' as link;
import 'package:past_papers/constants/file_name.dart' as file_name;
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

class Accounting extends StatefulWidget {
  const Accounting({super.key});

  @override
  State<Accounting> createState() => _AccountingState();
}

class _AccountingState extends State<Accounting> {
 
  DownloadPaper downloadPaper = DownloadPaper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Accounting'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Accounting',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          const Text('November'),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          const Divider(
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
            height: 1,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),

// The ListTile() goes here

);
```

Comment: what the parent widget of this, stateless of stateful ? can you create a sample widget that will reproduce the same error

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it's stateful. I have edited and included the simplified class.